# Read from uiimageView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I want to know it it's possible to take an image from a camera and if that image contain any numbers it reads them from the image and shows them in a textfield.
I read about ZBAr but it is quite a different thing.  Does anyone know anything similar to that?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tesseract is an open-source OCR engine that works on the iPhone:
http://robertcarlsen.net/dev/pocket-ocr
http://sites.google.com/site/olipion/cross-compilation/tesseract-ocr

It converts images to plain text.

Comment: ok thanx anne can you please explain a little more about this

Comment: @vijay, what do you want explained? OCR? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition